# Responsive Navbar with large Image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to make a responsive navbar which so far I have achieved the only thing left that I would like to do is fix how the navbar looks in smaller windows.

As you can see [small resolution](https://i.cyrex.io/otdwfa.png) the navbar overlaps the image when you get to smaller resolutions.

And when you are on desktop resolutions it looks like this [enter link description here](https://i.cyrex.io/lajsep.png) the navbar to the right doesn't quite look right.

If anyone could point me to some resources that would help me fix this or if anyone could explain what I would need to change that would be great.

Also can anyone tell me how I can link my code so that it makes it easier for you guys to see what I have done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few techniques you could use for your logo.

- remove any width or height attributes from the image tag and then scale it based on the viewport width. eg

**HTML**

```
<div class="header"> <img src="logo.jpg" class = "logo"> </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo{
    width:50vw;
    max-width:500px;
}
```

- you could add more than one image tag in your header, one for desktop and one for mobile. Use a different class for each then use CSS media queries to hide or show one logo at a time based on viewport width.

HTML

```
<div class="header"><img src="logo-desktop.jpg" class = "logo desktop"> <img src="logo-mobile.jpg" class = "logo mobile"> </div>
```

CSS

```
.logo{
    display: none;
}


.logo.mobile{
    display:block;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .logo.mobile{
        display:none;
    }
    .logo.desktop{
        display:block;
    }

}
```

- one of my favourite techniques is to use background images rather than using an image tag. This makes it easy to overlay text if needed, and it's efficient on mobile because you can use media queries to define different images at different viewports and just one will be downloaded.

I hope this helps!